# show complex function is injective in the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=e^{2iπ|z|}z$, how to prove this function is one to one on unit disk.
Generally ,What is useful technique or theorem to solve problems like this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset math.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\exp(2\pi i |z|)z = \exp(2 \pi i |w|)w$. Taking absolute values we see $|z| = |w|$. Now dividing both sides by $\exp(2\pi i |z|)$ we see $z = w$.

Comment: How about  f(z)=e^(2itπ|z|))z, where t is an number between 0,1?

Comment: @m.mir same argument, same proof. the exponential part has absolute value one so you get |z| = |w|, and then the rest cancels so you get z = w.